# Uninstall Microsoft Windows KB3177467 Update

Tags: windows

How can I uninstall Microsoft Windows KB3177467 Update from Windows Server 2008. When I select this update to be removed, there are no uninstall button and won't even uninstall when I double-click on it.

**Why I want to uninstall the update?**
I updated the server 3 days ago and since then the clients has been complaining about how slow the website is. I thought it might be the problem with CPU, RAM or bad programming but it wasn't.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Servicing stack updates cannot be uninstalled.

As this update has nothing to do with IIS (only patching), it is likely not to blame.